# Restrict input to a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating an aplication in javaScript, but I am a bit confused of RegExp. I need to make user type into textArea desired form of string and let aplication to work with it, so I need to restrict the textArea input.

I need to field be like this:
**760, 8,20, 50/3, 10,160/40, 3001**

with optional spaces after comma, and optional number of items, where some of them can be optionaly with sufix (*/1...)

also i would like to have similar pattern which behave simillary but there could be prefixes like this:

**st. 760,st. 8, st.20, st. 50/3, st. 10, st. 160/40, st. 3001**

also with optional spaces. I would be really happy if someone could help me with making this regExp, because I am a real begginer in creating this...

I've tried the following regex `((\d+)|((\d+)/(\d+))),(\s?)`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want a lot, what have you tried ?

Comment: i tried something like this:
`((\d+)|((\d+)/(\d+))),(\s?)`
but i think it doesn't cover whole problem...

Comment: @user2567998 Well you can always test your regex at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
^\d+(/\d+)?(\s*,\s*\d+(/\d+)?)*$
```

Then, for the second one:

```
^(st\.\s*)?\d+(/\d+)?(\s*,\s*(st\.\s*)?\d+(/\d+)?)*$
```

Remember, any time you can use the escape sequences, which will make your regex much clearer. So, instead of doing [0-9], use \d, and also use \s to accept all kinds of spaces (space, tab; etc).

Comment: this one is great! i slightly edited it: 
`/^(st\.\s*)?\d+(\/\d+)?(\s*,\s*(st\.\s*)?\d+(\/\d+)?)*$/im`
but it is exacly what I needed! thanks for taking your time and helping me!

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
^([ ]*[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)?[ ]*\,)*([ ]*[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)?[ ]*)$
```

and

```
^([ ]*(st\. )?[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)?[ ]*\,)*([ ]*(st\. )?[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)?[ ]*)$
```

sound about right

Comment: it looks pretty great, however when i type something like this:
`st. 760, gfn, st. 8 ` it also accepts this one, but i need to prevent to user write other symbols than digits (exept "st.")

Comment: Corrected, need to add ^ and $

Comment: this is very nice. Thank you very much for making your time and helping me! I will prefer cgledezma's pattern because it has oportunity to use \n new line and it is shorter but they are similar, thank you once more. I really apreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it could help you:

To select your field:

```
    ([0-9]+/[0-9]+[,]{0,1})|([0-9]+[,]{0,1})
```

To replace them:

```
    st\.\ &1&2
```

By using sed command line :

```
    sed -e "s/([0-9]+/[0-9]+[,]{0,1})|([0-9]+[,]{0,1})/st\.\ &1&2/g"
```

Comment: i don't need to have my string replaced and to have "st. " inserted before each number. I only need to have checked the textArea if it matches the regExp